# Google OAuth 2 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch random url parameter ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-api

I've done authentication via VK, Instagram, Facebook in my site by template below.
However google requires "Redirect URL".
My redirect URL is like this:

```
http://localhost:4588/main/AuthenticationCallback?__provider__=google%2B&__sid__=6f3cc5957e4742758719f9b7decc2c09
```

Parameter "**sid**" is random every time. So I can't give google precise URL. I tried to input `http://localhost:4588/main/AuthenticationCallback` as I did for Instagram and it worked for Instagram but Google keeps showing me "400 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch"

I've also tried to pass `http://localhost:4588/main/AuthenticationCallback` as URL parameter in authorization url to google below. But in this case method "IAuthenticationClient.RequestAuthentication" is not called at all.

Can you advise me what should I input as "Redirect URL" for my Google app?

Template class working with OAuth2:

```
public class GoogleAuthenticationClient : IAuthenticationClient
{
    public string appId;
    public string appSecret;
    private string redirectUri;

    public GoogleAuthenticationClient(string appId, string appSecret)
    {
        this.appId = appId;
        this.appSecret = appSecret;
    }

    string IAuthenticationClient.ProviderName
    {
        get { return "google+"; }
    }

    void IAuthenticationClient.RequestAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl)
    {
        var APP_ID = this.appId;
        this.redirectUri = context.Server.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString());

        var address = String.Format(
                "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&response_type=code&scope={2}",
                APP_ID, this.redirectUri, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
            );

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(address, false);
    }

    class AccessToken
    {
        public string access_token = null;
        public string user_id = null;
    }

    class UserData
    {
        public string uid = null;
        public string first_name = null;
        public string last_name = null;
        public string photo_50 = null;
    }

    class UsersData
    {
        public UserData[] response = null;
    }

    AuthenticationResult IAuthenticationClient.VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        try
        {
            string code = context.Request["code"];

            var address = String.Format(
                    "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&code={2}&redirect_uri={3}",
                    this.appId, this.appSecret, code, this.redirectUri);

            var response = GoogleAuthenticationClient.Load(address);
            var accessToken = GoogleAuthenticationClient.DeserializeJson<AccessToken>(response);

            address = String.Format(
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{0}?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg",
                    accessToken.user_id);

            response = GoogleAuthenticationClient.Load(address);
            var usersData = GoogleAuthenticationClient.DeserializeJson<UsersData>(response);
            var userData = usersData.response.First();

            return new AuthenticationResult(
                true, (this as IAuthenticationClient).ProviderName, accessToken.user_id,
                userData.first_name + " " + userData.last_name,
                new Dictionary<string, string>());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new AuthenticationResult(ex);
        }
    }

    public static string Load(string address)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    public static T DeserializeJson<T>(string input)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize<T>(input);
    }
}
```

Code in my Controller:

```
    public void ExternalLogin(string provider)
    {
        OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(
            client: new GoogleAuthenticationClient(
                    "APP_ID", "APP_CODE"),
            displayName: "google+", // надпись на кнопке
            extraData: null);

        ExternalLoginCallback(provider);
    }

    public void ExternalLoginCallback(string provider)
    {
        OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(provider, Url.Action("AuthenticationCallback"));
    }

    public ActionResult AuthenticationCallback()
    {
        var result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication();

        if (result.IsSuccessful == false)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var provider = result.Provider;
            var uniqueUserID = result.ProviderUserId;
            return RedirectToAction("Main", "Main");
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can authorise a redirect URI as explained below, but you can't add any parameters to the redirect uri, please see this answer on how the parameters can be passed to Google [google oauth2 redirect_uri with several parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722062/google-oauth2-redirect-uri-with-several-parameters)

The authorised redirect URI needs to be set when you created your client ("APP_ID", "APP_CODE") on the Google Cloud Console. Simply navigate to the API console for your project and edit the Web client to set the correct redirect URI you would like to use.

[image]

Comment: I've already tried to do this - I put there http://localhost:4588/main/AuthenticationCallback
But it gives me the same error
Maybe because my real URI has some parameters that are random every time I launch my authentication
`http://localhost:4588/main/AuthenticationCallback?__provider__=google%2B&__sid__=6f3cc5957e4742758719f9b7decc2c09`

Comment: Apparently you can't add any parameters to the redirect uri please see this answer on how the parameters can be passed to Google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722062/google-oauth2-redirect-uri-with-several-parameters

Comment: @omerio, you should post the proper answer (your comment) so it gets accepted instead

Comment: @Alexandra thanks, I've just updated the answer to include the answer in the comment