# facebook php sdk, retrieve parameters after login

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, sdk

I have a very simple php script that gets some data as parameters from the url and posts a link on a given facebook's pageId. Here is the simplyfied code:

```
session_start();

$message     = $_GET['message'];    
$pageID      = $_GET['pageID'];

$parametres = json_encode(array("message" => $message));    
$stateString = base64UrlDecode($parametres);

$app_id = '123456';
$app_secret = '987654';
$redirect_url = 'http://www.example.com/facebookScript/index.php';  

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
$sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

if(isset($sess)) {      

    try {
        $response = (new FacebookRequest(
          $sess, 'POST', '/'.$pageID.'/feed', array(
            'message'       => $message             
          )
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

    } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
        echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
        echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
    }  

} else {                
    echo '<a href='.$helper->getLoginUrl().'>Login with facebook</a>';
}
```

This code works fine, the only problem is that when I call it, I must first login with my facebook account following the `$helper->getLoginUrl()` method. After that a redirect to the `$redirect_url` is triggered to do the post on the users wall, but as the redirect happens I have no parameters on my url: i cant retrieve the message value or the pageID anymore.

I have readed about the 'state' parameter, but trying to use it like its said on the solution of this post:

[state parameter at redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722062/google-oauth2-redirect-uri-with-several-parameters)

doenst works for me. Gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request' in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\lib\Facebook\FacebookRequestException.php:104 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\lib\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php(268): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...', Object(stdClass), 400) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\lib\Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php(146): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\index.php(63): Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getSessionFromRedirect() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\lib\Facebook\FacebookRequestException.php on line 104
```

Looks like it doesnt allows modifications on the redirect url.

Any idea on how to retrieve the parameters value after the redirection due to the facebook login ?

Thanks.

Comment: Change your redirect url in facebook api from developers.facebook.com and then try again.

Comment: I dont understand, you mean the redirect from my app settings at developers.facebook.com ?

Comment: On the developer's app settings, you can set up your app domain URL and the redirect URL should be part of the app domain. That should allow the redirect URL to function properly.