# Youtube Redirect URI add parameter dynamically

Tags: youtube-api

I want to add a parameter in youtube API redirect uri dynamically. I know we can't change the redirect uri dynamically. Is there any way to modify the auth url to add a parameter there and extract it after authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722099/8342742) in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722062/google-oauth2-redirect-uri-with-several-parameters),

> 1. You cannot add anything to the redirect uri, redirect uri is constant as set in the app settings of Oauth. eg
>      :http://www.example.com/redirect.html
> 2. To pass several parameters to your redirect uri, have them stored in `state` parameter before calling Oauth url, the url after
>      authorization will send the same parameters to your redirect uri as
>      `state=THE_STATE_PARAMETERS`

For further studies, you can check this [documentation from YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/registering_an_application).