# How to add a param to google oauth 2

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am trying to make an authorize request with google oAuth using the code below

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('qweqweqweqwe');
$client->setClientSecret('vQWsd1Geweqweqweqwe');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/test1');

$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']);

if (request()->has('code')) {

    $credentials = $client->authenticate(request('code'));

    dd($credentials);

}
```

its working, but my question is: Is there any way to add user id on the request and get it back on callback ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very good point on adding that param is preventing csrf attacks also.

The way how you add a param on google authorization request and then get back the param on the callback request from google, is by setting a `base64` encoded json payload:

Before generating the Authorization url first off include the two functions to encode and decode the url params, simple:

```
public function base64UrlEncode($inputStr)
{
    return strtr(base64_encode($inputStr), '+/=', '-_,');
}


public function base64UrlDecode($inputStr)
{
    return base64_decode(strtr($inputStr, '-_,', '+/='));
}
```

Making the oauth request to google, make url params example:

```
$params = base64UrlEncode('{ "a" : "b" , "c" : 1 }');
```

In Google Client class there is a function `setState($state)` that you need to call before creating the url and pass the `$params` as parameters like:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('qweqweqweqwe');
$client->setClientSecret('vQWsd1Geweqweqweqwe');

$params = base64UrlEncode('{ "a" : "b" , "c" : 1 }');
$client->setState($params);

$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/test1');
```

Then the response will have state request param so in the callback route do:

```
Route::get('/callback', function(){


  $state = request()->get('state');    // GET['state'];
  $state = base64_decode(strtr($state, '-_,', '+/='));
  dd($state); // will output your params 
});
```

This answer somewhat based from: 
[here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722062/google-oauth2-redirect-uri-with-several-parameters/7722099#7722099)

Comment: @ishegg the explanantion there does not include specific code as this answer. So this answer its much more usefull than that one.

Comment: Maybe, but you need to give attribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `state` to send custom parameters with [`Google_Client::setState()`](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php#L554).

When setting up your Client:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('qweqweqweqwe');
$client->setClientSecret('vQWsd1Geweqweqweqwe');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/test1');
$client->setState('test=value');
```

And on callback, the parameters will be in `state` through GET:

```
var_dump($_GET["state"]); // test=value
```

You can send pretty much whatever you want, so try `json_encode()` or `url_encode()`ing your data if it gets too complex.