# Handling redirect URIs that include query parameters

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I need users to login from a page that has query parameters in the URI, and they need to be redirected back to this page after login. AAD doesn't allow response URIs to contain query parameters though. To make matters worse, the login page URI is dynamic (the query parameters determine the specific page the user is on), so I couldn't put just one response URI anyway. I also have no way of determining the exact parameters, so I can't list several either.

URI examples:
`https://example.com/content?page=5211`
`https://example.com/content?page=6952`

What can I do to have users redirected back to the login page so I can get an access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722062/google-oauth2-redirect-uri-with-several-parameters).

The answer refers to Google, but the same reason applies to Azure AD