# How to add Azure static web app URL to the Google OAuth 2.0 client ID redirect URL at Google developer console

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, google-developers-console, azure-static-web-app

I have created an Azure static web app with the default URL we usually get when it is deployed(eg: `https://xxx.1.azurestaticapps.net`).

I have created a login with google functionality in my app and locally it works fine. But when I try to add the static web app URL as a redirect URL at the Google developer console, under OAuth 2.0 client ID, it seems that it does not allow me to add the particular URL.

It just shows an error saying that an error occurred!

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: [Authentication and authorization for Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization?tabs=invitations#login) , [Configure your App Service or Azure Functions app to use Google login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-google) and [Google OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri with several parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722062/google-oauth-2-0-redirect-uri-with-several-parameters)