# Tomcat makes a new session after a redirect from Google OAuth 2.0 API. Why?

Tags: tomcat, oauth-2.0, antiforgerytoken, google-openidconnect

I am implementing Google's OpenID Connect (OAuth 2.0) in Tomcat.

The first step is to

1. [Create an anti-forgery state token](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#createxsrftoken)

which I did and thought I could store it as an attribute in the Tomcat HttpSession object "session".

But after Google redirects to my redirect URI (on the same Tomcat server), Tomcat has created a ***new*** session object for this HTTP Get.

I have looked and cannot find an explanation for this behavior.  I had expected that the original session object would be accessible on the redirect GET.

The flow is:

GET login.jsp from my Tomcat; store anti-forgery token in session this page has a button to login via Google

Push the button

GET accounts.google.com which returns a 302 with a location to my redirect.jsp

GET redirect.jsp from my Tomcat; display all attributes in session -- there are none

I was expecting the anti-forgery token to be in the session object.

I am considering storing the anti-forgery token in the filesystem, checking the creation date against the time of the redirect and checking the request.getRemoteAddr of the redirect against the original request as an alternative to using session.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated my answer. Google/oAuth provides fields for you to store your token in and they will send that data back to you in the URL query parameters of the redirect URL so no need for a session. See my answers below for an example link.

Comment: @Alan What Spring framework are you using? If you are using Spring, which I imagine you are, its not really Tomcat that is causing the new session.

Answer (score 0):

I misread your question. Yes you are looking for a place to keep the XSRF token but naturally tomcat is giving you a new session after authentication as expected. There are two options that I know of.

1. Google or the OAuth protocol provides you the option of placing the token in a "State" field that it will append as a query parameter when it redirects users back to your site and you can then pull the token out of the redirect URL parameters instead of a session. Here's an answer discussing it -> [Google OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri with several parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722062/google-oauth-2-0-redirect-uri-with-several-parameters)
2. Another option is put the token in a cookie and when the user returns pull the value out of the cookie and compare it to what you have in the database or if you dont want to hit the database you can store it as a JWT and just verify it in memory after pulling it out of the cookie.

Comment: Why do you say "but naturally tomcat is giving you a new session after authentication as expected"?  Why should tomcat give me a new session?

Comment: Why do you say "but naturally tomcat is giving you a new session after authentication as expected"?  Why should tomcat give me a new session?  The sequence of https traffic is:  GET google login.jsp (from my website)  GET Google's "authorization_endpoint" passing form data (as specified by Google) of:  'client_id', 'redirect_uri', 'response_type', 'scope', 'include_granted_scopes', 'state'  After much back and forth with Google and successfully logging in to Google, Google redirects back to the 'redirect_uri' specified in the form data, which is a URI on my website:  GET 'redirect_uri'

Comment: My initial question is: why does Tomcat create a new session for the last GET (to the redirect_uri) and not continue to use the session from the first GET google login.jsp (from my website)?

Comment: @Alan When you are not authenticated that represents a separate session. Upon authorization it would be expected that your session will be flushed and your userId will be placed inside the session. In fact lots of applications won't give you a session till you have authenticated because what is the purpose if you have no userId yet. For this reason you're expected to place extra interaction info in the extra fields Google is providing.